# Rails is not able to grab an object array when I render a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 controllers:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  @person = Person.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if @person && @person.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    session[:user_id] = @person.id
    render('people/index')
  else
    render('session/new')
  end
end

class PeopleController < ApplicationController

def index
  @person = Person.all
end
```

My view is the following:

```
...

<% @person.each do |p| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= p.name %></td>
  <td><%= p.gender %></td>
  <td><%= p.birthdate %></td>
  <td><%= p.interests_concatenated %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

When I enter a user's credential and try to login, I get the following error message:

NoMethodError in Sessions#create
Showing /Users/fizz/workspace/rails_people/app/views/people/index.html.erb where line #11 raised:
undefined method `each' for #Person:0x007fd345aa1778

It looks like Rails is not grabbing the Person.all array and setting it into the @person variable, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render` method just renders a template using the data in the current action.  You should use `redirect_to` instead.

From the [Rails layouts and rendering guide:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

> Another way to handle returning responses to an HTTP request is with
>   redirect_to. As you've seen, render tells Rails which view (or other
>   asset) to use in constructing a response. The redirect_to method does
>   something completely different: it tells the browser to send a new
>   request for a different URL.

You probably want something like this:

```
def create
  @person = Person.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if @person && @person.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    session[:user_id] = @person.id
    redirect_to people_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Note I also changed it to `render 'new'` since the controller is `sessions` not `session` and you don't even need to specify it in this case.

I would also consider renaming the `@person` instance variable in the `people#index` action to `@people`.

Comment: That worked, thank you for your explanation. So your saying by using render, Rails fetched people/index.html.erb using only the data inside sessions#create, while completely skipping over processing people#index?

Comment: Yep.  You need to make a new request to access a different controller action.  The render method doesn't make requests, but the redirect_to method does.